# Como puedo incluir una variable en una consulta de java

Tags: java, mysql

Quiero hacer una consulta "filtrando" por el valor que tenga en un `JTextField` pero no se como incluirlo en la consulta.

Tengo esto

```
int codmatricula = Integer.parseInt(txtcodmat.getText());
String consulta = "select * from notas where cod_matr = 'codmatricula' ";
ResultSet resulCons = encapsulaCons.executeQuery(consulta);
```

Comment: Tienes que concatenar la variable, de esta forma: String consulta = "select * from notas where cod_matr = ' "+ codmatricula  +" '  ";

Comment: @RodrigoCortés ponlo como respuesta ;)

Comment: Sería mejor si use parámetros para evitar ataques de SQL inyección.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solo concatenalo el valor  de `codmatricula` para poder crear tu consulta:

```
int codmatricula = Integer.parseInt(txtcodmat.getText());
String consulta = "select * from notas where cod_matr = "+ codmatricula;
ResultSet resulCons = encapsulaCons.executeQuery(consulta);
```

Si el tipo del campo `cod_matr` es una cadena debes incluir el valor entre comillas sencillas:

```
String consulta = "select * from notas where cod_matr = ' "+ codmatricula +" ' ";
```